# How to make emacs properly indent if-then-else construct in elisp

Tags: emacs, clojure

When I indent if-then-else construct in emacs lisp, the else block doesn't indent properly. What I get is:

```
(defun swank-clojure-decygwinify (path)
  "Convert path from CYGWIN UNIX style to Windows style"
  (if (swank-clojure-cygwin)
      (replace-regexp-in-string "\n" "" (shell-command-to-string (concat "cygpath -w " path)))
    (path)))
```

where else form is not indented at the same level as the then form. Is there an obvious way to fix this?

Comment: That is the proper indentation.

Comment: The *reason* why it gets indented like this is because the "else form" actually includes *all* the expressions after the "then" expression, and they *all* get indented at that level.  When thinking of `if` statements with that in mind, the default indentation makes sense.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That is the proper indentation. A quote from the manual:

> The word "else" is not written in the Lisp code; the else-part of an
>   `if' expression comes after the then-part.  In the written Lisp, the
>   else-part is usually written to start on a line of its own and is
>   indented less than the then-part:

```
 (if TRUE-OR-FALSE-TEST
     ACTION-TO-CARRY-OUT-IF-THE-TEST-RETURNS-TRUE
   ACTION-TO-CARRY-OUT-IF-THE-TEST-RETURNS-FALSE)
```

For example, the following `if` expression prints the message `4 is
not greater than 5!` when you evaluate it in the usual way:

```
 (if (> 4 5)                               ; if-part
     (message "4 falsely greater than 5!") ; then-part
   (message "4 is not greater than 5!"))   ; else-part
```

Note that the different levels of indentation make it easy to
distinguish the then-part from the else-part.  (GNU Emacs has several
commands that automatically indent `if` expressions correctly.  *Note
GNU Emacs Helps You Type Lists: Typing Lists.)

This is a feature, not a bug :-)

Answer (score 8):

I don't have the relevant documentation handy, but this seems to do what you want:

```
(put 'if 'lisp-indent-function nil)
```

Also, you misused the word "properly"; by definition, however emacs indents is "proper" :)

Comment: People do so often confuse the concepts of "properly" and "in the way that I have just come up with"

Answer (score 5):

The default style is proper -- for Emacs Lisp.  For Common Lisp and other flavors of Lisp, the "else" clause should be aligned underneath the "then" clause.  To get Common Lisp indendation, you have to do something like this:

```
(set (make-local-variable lisp-indent-function)
     'common-lisp-indent-function)
```

To get this to happen automatically, you can do something like this:

```
(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (set (make-local-variable lisp-indent-function)
                  'common-lisp-indent-function))))
```

Note, however, that Lisp-Emacs interaction packages, like Slime, may override the indentation behavior, and in that case, the above might do nothing.  The above should work in a basic Emacs.

Comment: Curious that this isn't the default for `lisp-mode` (or at least for `common-lisp-mode`, although I see now that is simply an alias for lisp-mode)

Answer (score 0):

Lead yourself to believe that Elisp is a Scheme and use [`progn`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/progn.html). That delimits the then and else expressions but indents them at the same column:

```
(defun swank-clojure-decygwinify (path)
  "Convert path from CYGWIN UNIX style to Windows style"
  (if (swank-clojure-cygwin)
      (replace-regexp-in-string "\n" "" (shell-command-to-string (concat "cygpath -w " path)))
    (progn
      (path))))
```